# Android DDMS File Explorer not showing the contents

Tags: android, file, emulation, explorer, ddms

I need to access the file contents on my Android Emulator. Whenever I run the DDMS it doesn't show any contents. I already tried:

1) Restarting ADB (adb kill and start)
2) Running the command as an Admin.

[image]

Comment: you can try deleting the existing AVD and create a new AVD and see if you can access.

Comment: I see DDMS File Explorer working on Android Emulators based on API 19 and 23, but shows a blank screen on API 25.   I am running AS2.2.2 on a Win7 box.   There is an existing (closed) bug report on this:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal you can use:

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackage cat /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/dbname.sqlite > /sdcard/dbname.sqlite"
```

to extract your database to sdcard folder

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem I change my emulator from api 24 to api 23 and then its work.
In fact i add new emulator and  change my emulator to api 23 and its work.